# Select raw data from multi table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to select raw data from multiple tables.

eg.

```
query = tempmodel.objects.raw('select empid as id,employee.empid,ccmaster.cscid from employee
                                left join ccmaster
                                on employee.cscid = ccmaster.cscid'
```

**Am I need to create a new model for `tempmodel` that includes all required fields?**

I already tried with `cursor.execute` but this only returns result value, not with the field.

How can I select raw for multi-table?

I already check that one=> [raw sql with multiple table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794816/django-python-raw-sql-with-multiple-tables) but honestly, I don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

raw() automatically maps fields in the query to fields on the model. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields)

I suggest you create a Model that includes all required fields and set the `managed` Meta option to False (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed)

i.e.

```
class TempModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

(Optional) In addition to that, maybe you could use a Custom Model Manager (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods)

Comment: Documentation is just used raw and print. I was confused there. Am I need to call serializer after calling raw? Like that `serializer = TsmtTempModelSerializer(query,many=True)` but this one got the error.Invalid object name `'db_tsmttempmodel'`.Thanks.